# Find general formula for $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac {(-1)^i i}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was able to find formulas for simpler expressions but I can't find the general formula for this one:

$\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac {(-1)^i i}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}$

I don't see any particular trend that would help me in the first solutions.

$P(1) = -1/3, P(2) = -3/15, P(3) = -36/175 ...$

And if I expand the sum I also fail to come up with an answer.
Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Did you really mean $21$ up there, or is it $2i$?

Comment: nice catch, it was 2i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{i}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2i-1}+\frac{1}{2i+1}\right)$

Then you have

$-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2.1-1}+\frac{1}{2.1+1}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2.2-1}+\frac{1}{2.2+1}\right)+\ldots+$

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a "telescoping" summation.  Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^i i}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}&=\frac14 \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}-\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac14 \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}-\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2(i-1)+1}\right)\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac14\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}-1\right)}
\end{align}$$